# Facebook: Stream publish popup throwing error when 'next' is null

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to post an fb feed from my application through the JS SDK.

If I fail to set the  next property to null I keep on getting an “error occurred message”. Can someone help?

```
var obj = {
            method: 'feed',
            link: link,
            picture: link,
            name: name,
            caption: caption,
            description: description,
            redirect_uri: "http://www.google.com/",
            next:null,
            app_id: facebookappid,
            actions: [
                { name: action_text, link: action_link }
            ]
```

I need to set next to redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**REMOVE** the `next` field, it's not supported. If you need to set the "next" link just use the `redirect_uri` field.